# Program exit status and $?

Tags: c++, exit-code

C++ Primer book i read says that

> The value returned from main is accessed in a system dependent manner.
>   On both UNIX and Windows systems, afar executing the program you must
>   issue an appropriate echo command. On UNIX we obtain the status by
>   echo $?

So, if the program is

```
int main ()
{
    return -88;
}
```

Why does `echo $?` not return it? (168 is printed upon `echo`)

Comment: what does `echo $?` return for you exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does, sort of. It'll convert the value to an unsigned 8-bit value, though, which is 256 − 88 = 168. That's part of the system-dependent mannerism.

Comment: @BjoernD: d'oh :-) (I had typed "265" into calc. But my "minus" looks prettier than yours.)

Answer (score 1):

Returning a value from `main` is the same as calling `std::exit` with that value. This is what a late draft of the standard says about `std::exit` (18.5, `status` is the value you call it with):

> Finally, control is returned to the host environment. If `status` is
>   zero or `EXIT_SUCCESS`, an implementation-defined form of the status
>   *successful termination* is returned. If `status` is `EXIT_FAILURE`, an implementation-defined form of the status *unsuccessful
>   termination* is returned. Otherwise the status returned is
>   implementation-defined.

Typically the value is either interpreted as-is or converted to a smaller (perhaps unsigned) type, but this really depends on your environment and implementation.